# Zend Validator for digits with negative mark

Tags: php, validation, zend-framework

Iam using zend framework and zend form with validator `DIGIT` like this :

```
    $ZV_Digit=new Zend_Validate_Digits();
    $credit = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('credit');
    $credit->setLabel('current credit');
    $credit->setValidators(array($ZV_Digit));
```

But it does not pass negative numbers and gives this error :

```
'-4000' contains not only digit characters
```

What can I do now?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From Zend Framework [documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.validate.set.html#zend.validate.set.digits.options)

```
Note: Validating numbers
When you want to validate numbers or numeric values, 
be aware that this validator only validates digits.
This means that any other sign like a thousand separator
or a comma will not pass this validator.
In this case you should use Zend_Validate_Int or Zend_Validate_Float
```